# Delete all records except one in database

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, db2, spring-data

I have to delete all the records for matching ID except one. There is no dat column which I can consider. The dtatastruchtur e is like below:

```
OBJECT_ID - primary key
DOC_ID
FIRST NAME
LAST NAME
```

I am trying to delete all the `doc_ID` that match to specific number except one through jpa. Couldn't find any jpa specific function.  I am implementing JPARepository. There is delete All, Is there any way I can achieve this?

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public User save(User user);

    public void deleteAllByDocID(String docID);
}
```

UPDATE: Sorry was unsure of the database: we are using DB2 and I tried to write down these queries:

```
  DELETE FROM USR WHERE OBJ_ID NOT IN (SELECT OBJ_ID FROM USR WHERE DOC_OBJ_ID='91298' FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY); - this gives me error transaction log is full.
```

ANd this:

```
  DELETE FROM USR WHERE OBJ_ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP(1) OBJ_ID FROM USR WHERE DOC_OBJ_ID='91298'); - and this give me error TOP is not a function
```

Comment: Get all objects by the user, iterate over them, delete all of them until the count is length-2 or size-2, done?

Comment: @maio290 Why -2?

Comment: @Antoniossss - woops, that was some thought, If you use <=, it's -2, if you're using <, it's -1. Just a bit of a fuss in my head, and I fully agree, < is more common.

Comment: I was trying not to iterate over the records.

Comment: @ILRNew, if you can do it in SQL, you can use that SQL as a native query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to use a custom query, you can do it like this :

in your repository define these two methods

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

   User findFirstByDocIDOrderByObjectIDAsc(String docID);
   void deleteAllByDocIDAndObjectIDNot(String docID, Long objectID);
}
```

and then in your service layer do this

```
User user = repository.findFirstByDocIDOrderByObjectIDAsc(docID);
if(user !=null) deleteAllByDocIDAndObjectIDNot(docID, user.objectID);
```

note that since this solution is using derived delete query, it will delete the records one by one.

Comment: Thank you Reza.. I thought this will be perfect.. But I my hbm xml file is like this:

Comment: <many-to-one name="Document" class="Document" not-null="true">
            <column name="DOC_OBJ_ID"/>
        </many-to-one>

Comment: And because of which it complains me -  No property docObjectID found for type User. Also I cant modify my USER class as it is added as part of external jar..

Comment: my answer was based on the sample `Repository` code you provided. You need to replace the `ObjectID` with the property that is identifier property of your `User` object and `DocID` with `Document` which is the property name based on your mapping. If you can provide the full mapping of your `User` object, I can update my answer based on that.

Comment: glad to be able to help. will appreciate if you accept the solution as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could `COUNT`  matching records first and then delete with `LIMIT N-1`

Comment: but that will be sql right ? NOt the jpa specific query?

Comment: You can do it in JPA. FYI what you are using (spring repositories) is not JPA as I got the feeling you think it is.

Comment: So now the question is can I do it using spring repository?

Comment: Just use @Query annotation ;)